# how to convert two lists into a dictionary (one list is the keys and the other is the values)?

Tags: python

This is code in IDLE2 in python, and error.

I need to include each "data" element as key and value "otro", in an orderly manner. Well "data" and "otro" it's list with 38 string's, as for "dik" it's an dictionary.

```
>>> for i in range(len(otro)+1):
    dik[dato[i]] = otro[i]  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#206>", line 2, in <module>
    dik[dato[i]] = otro[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

this problem is range(0, 38) 
output -> (0, 1,2,3 ... 37) and it is all messy

Comment: Can you read out loud the last line and think about what the interpreter is telling you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think something like:

```
dik = dict(zip(dato,otro))
```

is a little cleaner...

---

If `dik` already exists and you're just updating it:

```
dik.update(zip(dato,otro))
```

---

If you don't know about [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), you should invest a little time learning it.  It's super useful.

```
a = [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ]
b = ['a','b','c','d']
zip(a,b)   #=>   [(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d')] #(This is actually a zip-object on python 3.x)
```

`zip` can also take more arguments (`zip(a,b,c)`) for example will give you a list of 3-tuples, but that's not terribly important for the discussion here.

This happens to be exactly one of the things that the [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) "constructor" (type) likes to initialize a set of `key-value` pairs.  The first element in each `tuple` is the `key` and the second element is the `value`.

Comment: +1. This is the best solution, although RocketDonkey's answer does a good job of explaining why the current solution fails.

Comment: @Lattyware -- Agreed.  +1 to his :)

Comment: @mgilson +1's all around - this is definitely cleaner.

Comment: it's ok!!!  thanks, gracias !!

Comment: muchachos es el poder de python! dictionary.update(zip(list1,list2))

Answer (score 10):

The error comes from this: `range(len(otro)+1)`. When you use `range`, the upper value isn't actually iterated, so when you say `range(5)` for instance, your iteration goes `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, where position `5` is the element `4`. If we then took that list elements and said `for i in range(len(nums)+1): print nums[i]`, the final `i` would be `len(nums) + 1 = 6`, which as you can see would cause an error.

The more 'Pythonic' way to iterate over something is to not use the `len` of the list - you iterate over the list itself, pulling out the index if necessary by using `enumerate`:

```
In [1]: my_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']

In [2]: for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
   ...:     print index, item
   ...:
   ...:
0 one
1 two
2 three
```

Applying this to your case, you can then say:

```
>>> for index, item in enumerate(otro):
...    dik[dato[index]] = item
```

However keeping with the Pythonicity theme, @mgilson's `zip` is the better version of this construct.

Comment: -1. This may be the issue, but it doesn't really make the code better. Why loop over indices?

Comment: `for i, o in enumerate(otro):` is a little "neater". Or `for d, o in zip(dato, otro):`. Or `dik = dict(zip(dato,otro))` instead of the whole block.

Comment: @Lattyware Ha, reading my mind - I'm augmenting now :)

Comment: @millimoose Why do you need the index here? ``zip()`` the iterables if you need to loop over two.

Comment: @Lattyware Because I thought of `zip()` about 0.5 seconds after submitting the comment ;)

Comment: Downvote changed to an upvote, this is a good answer now.

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks - with the answer as it was, definitely a justified downvote :)

Comment: thanks!!! i don't speaking inglish expert, and sorry!! gracias

Comment: @opmeitle No problemo - que tengas suerte con todo!

Comment: @RocketDonkey -- estoy celoso.  quiero a aprender espanol.

Comment: @mgilson Jeje, en mi opinion, es mas facil para aprender cuando escuches musica y trates de traducir cada palabra. I'm garbage at it, but definitely good times :)

Comment: @mgilson Ha, good call on the edit :)