# given a list of value, and a list of key, How can I make a dictionary from both list?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert two lists into a dictionary (one list is the keys and the other is the values)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537595/how-to-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-one-list-is-the-keys-and-the-other-i)

if I have a list of integer:

```
L=[1,2,3,4]
```

and I have a list of tuple list:

```
K=[('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f'),('g','i')]
```

how can I make a list of dict where the key is item in K, and the value is integer in L,where each integer is correspond to the item in K

```
d={('a','b'):1,('c','d'):2,('e','f'):3,('g','i'):4}
```

Comment: can I do it with a for loop? I haven't learn zip yet

Comment: See the answers in the duplicate link I posted.  One of those does it using a loop.  (And explains where the original poster [OP] failed in their attempt at doing it with a loop).  The other answer posted there uses `zip` and explains briefly what it does/how it works.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine two iterables into pairs, then pass that to the `dict` constructor:

```
d = dict(zip(K, L))
```

Quick demo (take into account that `dict` does not retain ordering):

```
>>> L=[1,2,3,4]
>>> K=[('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f'),('g','i')]
>>> dict(zip(K, L))
{('e', 'f'): 3, ('a', 'b'): 1, ('c', 'd'): 2, ('g', 'i'): 4}
```

With a for loop and no `zip()`:

```
d={}
for i, key in enumerate(K):
    d[key] = L[i]
```

Comment: can I do it with a for loop? I haven't learn zip yet

Comment: @user1805048 -- No better time than now to look up the documentation (which Martijn did for you :) and read it.  `zip` is particularly useful.

Comment: @user1805048: Tsk, tsk, cheating on our homework, are we? Easy enough, until you tell me you haven't learned about `enumerate()` yet. Then we'll move on to `range(len(K))` and then have to explain about `range()` too, won't I?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with `zip`:

```
zipped = zip(K, L)
d = dict(zipped)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you NEED to use a for loop (is this your homework?), you can do one starting with:

```
d = {}
for i in xrange(len(K)):
```

You should figure out the last line yourself.

Looping over indices is a technique you can use in other languages, and is sometimes (very rarely) necessary in python. In general, you should use python's high-level language features to make your code easier to read easier to read and debug.